# fedex integration with laravel

Tags: laravel, github, integration

I am integrating following git-hub library but getting following problem.

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Arkitecht\FedEx\Laravel\Providers\FedExServiceProvider' not found

I am doing same as mentioned in Readme file of project. GitHub project link is as follows:
[Architecht](https://github.com/Arkitecht/fedex-laravel)[Architect Readme](https://github.com/Arkitecht/fedex-laravel/commit/5ba66974554adb317056f38869a21191026353af)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you placed `use Fedex` in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

**Put:**

```
Arkitecht\FedEx\Laravel\Providers\FedExServiceProvider::class,
```

in **providers** within **config/app.php**

**Don't** write **"Arkitecht\FedEx\Laravel\": "src/"** in your composer file.

also, you may need to run **composer dump-autoload** in the root folder

Comment: I have already written **"Arkitecht\FedEx\Laravel\Providers\FedExServiceProvider::class,"** in **providers** and didn't write ** "Arkitecht\FedEx\Laravel\": "src/"** in composer file. but as per directory structure Providers directory and files are not there in src folder. Please let me know after **composer update ** why providers and controllers folder is not created. And if i download from github then where to place and how to configure **composer.json**

Comment: how it's not create? paste the debug shown when run **composer update**